# How does censoring an observation at baseline impact regression coefficients in survival analysis (e.g., Cox proportional-hazards model)?

Tags: survival, regression-coefficients, cox-model, censoring

I have a dataset with 28000 patients at baseline, of which approximately 1100 have had only a baseline visit. A logical choice would be to censor these observations (0) at time 0. However, I wonder how this would impact the Cox proportional-hazards model. For example, would it overestimate or underestimate the effect? Would it decrease precision of effects? Or would the observations be excluded from the analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on (1) whether you have information about the patients other than what is available from your recorded visits and (2) whether the lack of a second visit contains information important for your study.

(1) Say that the event of interest is death and you have access to death records that would cover all those 1100 patients if any of them had died. Then you certainly would want to consider including them in the study, with their time from study entry to death or to last known time alive used as event or censoring times, respectively.

If you only have information available from patients at visits, however, then those 1100 won't enter into any calculations. Individuals only contribute to the calculations that fit a Cox model when they are in the "risk set" at the time of an event. The "risk set" at an event time consists of the individuals who could have been observed to have an event at that time.

Unless you have events at `time = 0` (which some software won't even accept, as I recall), individuals with *information only available from a baseline visit at* `time = 0` would never be in a risk set at later times. So whether you omit them yourself or not, the Cox model should be the same.

(2) In that latter situation, however, you must ask whether the lack of later visits by those 1100 individuals contains information relevant to your study. That could invalidate the modeling itself due to informative censoring.

As an extreme example: what if those 1100 all died before they had an opportunity for a second visit and you didn't have information that they had died? You should at least see whether those lacking later visits differed systematically from others in terms of covariates of interest.

Also, if you only collect information from patients at defined visit times then you might have what's called "interval-censored" data, in which you know that an event happened during some time window but don't know exactly when. That can be an issue with studies of cancer recurrence, for example. That can require modeling with special techniques designed to handle such data.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive and helpful response! The event is treatment failure, defined as discontinuing a tumor necrosis factor inhibitor (a medicine, biological more specifically). Unfortunately, since the data is anonymized to me, I cannot retrieve additional information regarding these individuals. However, you did make an excellent suggestion about investigating their characteristics and comparing them with the rest of the group.

Comment: As for the interval-censored data part, that could be the case since, in some situations, I have a variable called "end-of-follow-up," which is the last date that the patients have been observed. But it is unclear if it is also confirmed that a patient is still on treatment at that time, so I have decided not to use it and be more conservative and chose the last patient visit as the endpoint of treatment.